# Push-Pull Workout Routine without a separate Leg-Day?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, splits

I'd like to, in the future, use a Push-Pull workout routine without a separate training day for my legs. In a 3-split the extra training day for legs essentially would result in something like an extra rest day before the training days for the upper body begin again.

So I'm wondering: **Is a Push-Pull workout routine with 4 training and 3 rest days a week suitable to recover enough from it in order to not overtrain over time?** That would be a cycle of Push, Pull, Rest, Push, Pull, Rest, Rest per week.

A little about myself and my training progress: I'm going to the gym for almost a year now. I'm a pretty skinny guy and therefore focussing on compound movements. I like my workouts to be around 60-75 minutes (including general warmup and specific warmup sets for every exercise) and I really dislike full body workout plans. Thats why I personally prefer a 2-split, which I currently do since about 4 months in an Upper-Lower-Body workout routine.

Comment: Do you mean if one of the most popular splits tested for decades is viable? Absolutely yes. You have a lot of fat in your question you need to cut. It makes it confusing to read if you start a paragraph talking about one split and then jump to something different and I don't know what's going on. Also please note that this is not a forum but a q&a. It sounds to me as if you want more of a general discussion and exchange of experiences than asking a clear, non-vague question. There are many weight training forums on the net, you might get more for your efforts there

Comment: @Raditz_35 I edited the question and cut out a lot of useless information according to your comment.